# Example of grammar (lex/yacc) for tree description

Tags: tree, ocaml, grammar, ocamllex, menhir

I want to parse a tree from a file that will describe this tree (which actually is a taxonomy).

I am looking for examples of grammar (ideally lex/yacc files) that provides description of trees. It would be better if that described trees were not binary search trees but instead trees where each node (possibly) has several children (is it called a family tree? planar tree?).

Ideally, it would be perfect if this lex/yacc would actually be included in an OCaml library. But any good grammar for tree description will satisfy me.

I tried to find examples through Google or Stackoverflow but research results are overwhelmed by parse tree-related questions.
I could make a grammar myself but I would like to see example first in order to do have a good starting point.

Comment: You should use ocamllex and menhir which are integrated with OCaml instead of lex and yacc. Without knowing the syntax of your tree file, I can't help you a lot.

Comment: Don't worry, I indeed intend to use ocamllex/ocamlyacc (or maybe Menhir). I am just looking for something already done regarding tree description grammar (maybe with lex/yacc, in that case, I will translate the code to ocamllex/ocamlyacc).

Comment: I use ocamllex and ocamlyacc to parse trees in POY; check http://code.google.com/p/poy/source/browse/src/nexus/grammar.mly#849 . I have to admit, we take into account a number of extra formatting situations, but it's another taste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my attempt at creating a minimal example of parsing a tree:

I assume trees are represented as `name_of_the_node(child(...), other_child(...), ...)`. For instance, here is a simple tree with a root and 3 leaves: `root(first_leaf(), second_leaf(), third_leaf())`.

**lexer.mll**

```
{
  open Parser
  open Lexing

  exception Bad_char of char
}

rule main = parse
| ' ' | '\t' | '\n' { main lexbuf }
| ',' { COMMA }
| '(' { LP }
| ')' { RP }
| ['a'-'z' '_']+ as s { IDENT s }
| _ as c { raise (Bad_char c) }
```

**parser.mly**

```
%{
  open Tree
%}

%token <string> IDENT
%token COMMA LP RP

%start <Tree.t> tree

%%

tree:
label = IDENT LP children = separated_list(COMMA, tree) RP { T(label, children) }
```

**tree.ml**

```
type t = T of string * t list
```

to compile:

```
ocamllex lexer.mll
ocamlc -c tree.ml
menhir --infer -v parser.mly
ocamlc -c parser.mli
ocamlc -c parser.ml
ocamlc -c lexer.ml
```

to test into toplevel:

```
ocaml tree.cmo parser.cmo lexer.cmo
```

and then:

```
let tree_of_string s = Parser.tree Lexer.main (Lexing.from_string s);;
tree_of_string "toto (titi(), tata(tutu()))";;
```